# Issue with powershell split for New Line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to split a txt doc in Powershell based on a New Line. The script worked okay when splitting on a ',' but now I've changed it to use [Environment]::NewLine it only seems to be picking the last line up.

This is the part of the script that should be splitting by newline:

```
 Get-Content  C:\Bindings.txt | Foreach-Object{
 $hostHeaders = $_.Split([Environment]::NewLine,
 [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
 }
```

The .txt document looks like so:

```
http:*:80:test.com 
http:*:80:test2.com 
http:*:80:test1.com
```

Any ideas on how I can make it split on the New Line and not only see the last line or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've 3 methods for you

I've prepared a .txt file

```
(Get-Content  C:\temp\Bindings.txt)
http:*:80:test.com 
http:*:80:test2.com 
http:*:80:test1.com
```

And now 3 methods

```
(Get-Content  C:\temp\Bindings.txt) -split"`r`n"
(Get-Content  C:\temp\Bindings.txt) -split "[Environment]::NewLine"
(Get-Content  C:\temp\Bindings.txt).Split([Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

the result is like this

```
http:*:80:test.com 
http:*:80:test2.com 
http:*:80:test1.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. The default behavior of Get-Content with a text file is to split on the new-line and return an array of strings:

```
PS C:\...\Can Delete 3>Get-Content data.txt
http:*:80:test.com
http:*:80:test2.com
http:*:80:test1.com
PS C:\...\Can Delete 3>$object = Get-Content data.txt
PS C:\...\Can Delete 3>$object.GetType()                                                  
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\...\Can Delete 3>$object.count
3
PS C:\...\Can Delete 3>$object[0]
http:*:80:test.com
PS C:\...\Can Delete 3>$Object | Get-Member                                               

   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
...
```